# Design pattern for building database query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

Today i was doing self-review of my code and code didn't look nice to me (Although it is working as intended). So i want a better way of doing the same.
Following is the case:

1. In my webservice, client can perform search operation on records by n number of search criteria ( one possible criteria can be `get me all the staff whose name contains A and who has designation Teacher`. So for such query i have many if statements that is making string query accordingly. but this is looking ugly to me. Is their any way to achieve this using `PreparedStatement`.

**Ugly code looks like below**

```
private String getSearchQuery(Staff staffEntity) {
    boolean hasAnySearchParam = false;
    String query = null;
    StringBuilder querybuilder = new StringBuilder("select * from " + DBConstants.StaffBasicInfo.tableName + " left outer join " + DBConstants.StaffAdvInfo.tableName + " on "
            + DBConstants.StaffBasicInfo.staffId + " = " + DBConstants.StaffAdvInfo.staff_adv_info_staffId + " where");
    if (staffEntity.getName() != null && (!staffEntity.getName().isEmpty())) {
        querybuilder.append(" " + DBConstants.StaffBasicInfo.staffname + " Like '%" + staffEntity.getName() + "%'");
        querybuilder.append(" and");
        hasAnySearchParam = true;
    }
    if (staffEntity.getDesignation() != null && (!staffEntity.getDesignation().isEmpty())) {
        querybuilder.append(" " + DBConstants.StaffBasicInfo.designation + " Like '%" + staffEntity.getDesignation() + "%'");
        querybuilder.append(" and");
        hasAnySearchParam = true;
    }
    if (staffEntity.getAge() != null) {
        querybuilder.append(" " + DBConstants.StaffBasicInfo.age + " = " + staffEntity.getAge());
        querybuilder.append(" and");
        hasAnySearchParam = true;
    }
    if (staffEntity.getUsername() != null && (!staffEntity.getUsername().isEmpty())) {
        querybuilder.append(" " + DBConstants.StaffAdvInfo.username + " Like '%" + staffEntity.getUsername() + "%'");
        querybuilder.append(" and");
        hasAnySearchParam = true;
    }
    if (staffEntity.getRole() != null && (!staffEntity.getRole().isEmpty())) {
        querybuilder.append(" " + DBConstants.StaffAdvInfo.role + " Like '%" + staffEntity.getRole() + "%'");
        querybuilder.append(" and");
        hasAnySearchParam = true;
    }
    if (false == hasAnySearchParam) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Check Json: No parameter to search");
    } else {
        // need to clean query.
        query = querybuilder.substring(0, querybuilder.length() - 3);
    }
    return query;
}
```

**Note** Right now i am more concerned about code clarity, simplicity and ease to use, i can think of performance issues later.

Comment: The visitor pattern is a good approach for Dynamic type searching, that way you create yourself a Teacher Visitor and an Age Visitor , they pull the details off the object you actually want.

Comment: @KennethClark thanks. I will check it out, what exactly it is and how it will solve my problem.

Comment: If you wanted to "reinvent the wheel" you could create yourself a column annotation, add the annotation to the get methods. loop through all methods with the @column(name="field_name") and build your query from that and fire the getmethod .. that way you have a really generic way of building a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular case I would use static query with params where params are set from java

```
WHERE
...
  and (:userNameParam is null or staffname like concat('%',:staffnameParam,'%'))
  and (:userNameParam is null or username like concat('%',:userNameParam ,'%'))
...
```

Then just pass parameters userNameParam, userNameParam etc. If they are null or empty just pass null.

Your way leaves possibility for SQL injection

Comment: any reference to learn the syntax and concept will help me more. I need to know what does `:` mean in `:userNameParam`

Comment: http://www.dineshonjava.com/2012/12/using-namedparameterjdbctemplate-in.html#.U2t8Vvl_v8o or http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-named-parameter-jdbc-template.html but you can use normal parameter ? just pass the same userName value twice

Comment: Both the articles uses `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` which seems to `Spring's` utility. I am working on `struts2` framework.

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077706/core-java/named-parameters-for-preparedstatement.html see this